# Mac VNC client that supports Raspberry Pi 5 and rescaling?

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to remotely connect to my Raspberry Pi 5 from an M1 Mac laptop.

The officially recommended client is [Tiger VNC Viewer](https://tigervnc.org/), which connects fine, but can't rescale the display at all.
This is a problem for a device that outputs 4K resolution viewing on a laptop screen.

- [Chicken of the VNC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/) hasn't been updated for years and doesn't work on M1 macs.
- [Remote Ripple](https://remoteripple.com/download/) doesn't connect to the Pi - gives an error
- MacOS's built-in Screen Sharing app won't connect - says "unable to communicate"
- [Screens for mac](https://edovia.com/en/screens-mac/) (demo version) failed to connect.
- [RealVNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) works, and scales, but is incredibly slow.

I'd prefer free, but willing to pay if necessary. What's my best option?